# Issues in ClientSession making tcp connections

Tags: python, concurrency, connection-pooling, scalability, python-asyncio

I am using asyncio to make asynchronous api calls to my server which is a dummy server and just returns ack.

```
import aiohttp
import time
import asyncio
import uvloop

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())

def _get_session_headers() -> dict:
    return {}

start=time.time()
conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=10240)
_session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn,headers=_get_session_headers())


async def test(data, value): 
    async with _session.request('POST', "http://target:8080/path", data=data) as response:
        buffer = await response.read()
        return buffer


data = initialize_data()

async def run():
    tasks = []
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(10000):
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(test(data, i)))
    end = time.time() 
    print(end-start)
    responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    await responses

start = time.time()
ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ioloop.run_until_complete(run())
end = time.time()
print(end-start)

task=ioloop.create_task(_session.close())
ioloop.run_until_complete(task)
ioloop.close()
```

I have set the number of open files to 10240 so that I don't have too many files open issue. So I try to make 10K concurrent connections, this takes around 10 sec. I am trying to figure out where the bottleneck is

One thing, I realized is that after I start the script, it takes around 5-6 seconds for tcp connections to be established.

`` sudo lsof -i -a -p `ps aux | grep python | grep myservice | awk -F " " '{print $2}'` | wc -l ``

I tried to check the number of tcp connections made by my process right after running the program. But it takes around 5-6 seconds for connections to be shown. I mean the above command shows 0 for the first 5-6 seconds. So I am wondering why it is taking so long. After that the script is able to make 10K tcp connections and finishes.

I tried to change the url to http://google.com instead of http://target:8080/path, but still it takes around 5-6 seconds for any tcp connection to show. I am thinking why it is taking so long. Any suggestions?
Also AFAIK, the ClientSession has connection pool, so it should have been much faster. Am I using the ClientSession incorrectly, I mean is there a way to initialize it properly so that the tcp connections are faster

Here is the cprofile of my run

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    1.076    0.538   12.594    6.297 {method 'run_until_complete' of 'uvloop.loop.Loop' objects}
    10664    0.850    0.000    0.937    0.000 {method 'feed_data' of 'aiohttp._http_parser.HttpParser' objects}
    25000    0.836    0.000    1.088    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:796(_wrap_create_connection)
    10664    0.719    0.000    1.722    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client_proto.py:140(data_received)
    10000    0.397    0.000    0.402    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:176(request)
    40000    0.345    0.000    8.552    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:180(_request)
    60000    0.313    0.000    1.157    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna/core.py:231(check_label)
    19998    0.311    0.000    0.371    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/locks.py:22(wait)
    20000    0.265    0.000    0.265    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py:635(_prepare_headers)
    10000    0.262    0.000    0.262    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'multidict._multidict.CIMultiDict' objects}
   270000    0.240    0.000    0.478    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna/intranges.py:38(intranges_contain)
    40143    0.147    0.000    9.338    0.000 grpc.py:31(test)
    20000    0.145    0.000    0.178    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py:528(read)
    10000    0.142    0.000    0.436    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py:477(send)
522950/522949    0.140    0.000    0.207    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
    10000    0.133    0.000    0.212    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py:275(update_headers)
    20000    0.132    0.000    0.594    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py:679(start)
    30000    0.126    0.000    1.885    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py:809(_create_direct_connection)
    60000    0.125    0.000    0.160    0.000 /home/me/venv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna/core.py:63(check_bidi)
   270000    0.120    0.000    0.120    0.000 {built-in method _bisect.bisect_left}
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: *it takes around 5-6 seconds for connections to be shown. [...] So I am wondering why it is taking so long.* I suspect DNS lookups. Try replacing `target` with its IP address to see if you get better performance.

Comment: @user4815162342 I tried that. The thing is if I lower down the number of concurrent requests like lets say 5000, to 2000, it takes less time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your response. Have you tried replacing the target host name with the IP address? Did the performance improve in that case?

Comment: @user4815162342. Yes I have tried that.

Comment: And it still takes several seconds for any connections to show? It might be useful to `strace` the program to see what it's actually doing.

Comment: @user4815162342 I changed the batch size to 1000, now the connections are persistent. So for every batch, no new tcp connections are created but the existing ones are used. However, still the time taken is high